# php5-curl not getting installed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, google-compute-engine, php-extension

I have execute the below

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

result was

```
root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html# sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5-curl is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgcrypt11-dev libgnutls-dev libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libp11-kit-dev
  librtmp-dev libtasn1-6-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html#
```

But when i try php -m command it shows only below modules.Kindly help me on this

```
root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html# php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: Try `sudo php5enmod curl`

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: Do You see curl when executing `php -ini | grep curl` ?

Comment: and You can list all included configuration files using `php --ini` command

Comment: It says like this. `root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html# php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: this is the out put I am getting
`# php -ini | grep cur
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you found a solution to your issue, but anyway, it may help someone else.
I was in the same situation and wanted to install curl for php5.6 I used the same command as yours but didn't work until I found this on some forums

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl php5.6-gd php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-xml php5.6-xmlrpc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with install required dependency

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

after this restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
or
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: I tried this. curl module is not there when i execute `php -m` :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extension is enabled.

```
cd /etc/php5/apache2/

sudo nano php.ini
```

add this command: `extension=curl.so`

then restart apache again

Comment: Still same  :( no differnce.